# StormCrawler AJAX/Dynamic content parsing

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I would like to know the current version of stormcrawler supports the AJAX/Dynamic content parsing and store it in elasticsearch.

I know there is a enhancement being worked on, here is the link: https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/issues/144

Appreciate your help

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 0):

There is a [separate branch](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/jBrowserDriver) which has not yet been merged. You can already use it and your feedback would help make it part of the next release.

Comment: BTW this has now been merged into the main branch and will be in the forthcoming release. See http://digitalpebble.blogspot.co.uk/2017/04/crawl-dynamic-content-with-selenium-and.html